# Change text on WebAuthn faceID prompt/dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, prompt, mobile-website, webauthn

I'm trying to integrate with *WebAuthn* for user authentication.

Below is the code I'm currently using:

```
const credOptions = {
    publicKey: {
      rp: {
        name: 'test inc',
        id:'login.test.com'
      },
      user,
      authenticatorSelection: {
        authenticatorAttachment: 'platform',
        requireResidentKey: true,
        userVerification: 'preferred'
      },
      pubKeyCredParams: [
        {
          type: 'public-key',
          alg: -7
        }
      ],
      attestation: 'direct',
      timeout: 60000,
      challenge
    }
  };
  try {
    const cred = await navigator.credentials.create(credOptions);
    return cred;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

### Question

- In below screenshot is it possible for me to change the text under "**Sign In**" and "**Do you want to ...**" shown on WebAuthn prompt/dialog for FaceID or TouchID.
- Basically I want to show custom text in these two fields ex:

  - `Sign In` --> `Enroll`
  - `Do you want to allow "login.com" to use FaceID`
    --> `Do you want to allow "Paypal" to use FaceID?`

I tried to change Relying party(`rp`) info in `credOptions` but I don't see expected results.

**Can anyone please guide if this is feasible.**

[image: webauthn prompt screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately that is an OS-level prompt that cannot be customized. This is a common limitation of the WebAuthn API - browser and OS modals that appear in response to `navigator.credentials.create()` and `.get()` cannot be manipulated via JS because they are handled by the browser or OS itself in a context that is purposefully not exposed to the webpage for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not likely to do so with arbitrary text ("Enroll" and "Paypal") as the text is being provided by the system and the user trusts the system to properly represent what is going on.

Having piecewise replaceable text may also interfere with localization decisions they have made in their UX.

Finally, there is not a way defined to do this within the WebAuthn javascript.

What you may consider doing is providing feedback to Apple around this and particularly different verbiage you would like or consider, e.g, "Sign in" vs "Sign up" vs "Continue". These three coincidentally are terms from their [UX guidelines for 'Sign in with Apple'](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/), and exposed in localized form by the OS.